# Ant design upload cannot upload big file

Tags: vue.js, antd

in the latest version of ant-design-vue, we're no longer able to upload bigger image.

```
<template>
 <a-upload
    name="avatar"
    list-type="picture-card"
    class="avatar-uploader"
    :show-upload-list="false"
    action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
    :before-upload="beforeUpload"
    @change="handleChange"
  >
    <img v-if="imageUrl" :src="imageUrl" alt="avatar" />
    <div v-else>
      <a-icon :type="loading ? 'loading' : 'plus'" />
      <div class="ant-upload-text">
        Upload
      </div>
    </div>
  </a-upload>
</template>
<script>
function getBase64(img, callback) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', () => callback(reader.result));
  reader.readAsDataURL(img);
}
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      imageUrl: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange(info) {
      if (info.file.status === 'uploading') {
        this.loading = true;
        return;
      }
      if (info.file.status === 'done') {
        // Get this url from response in real world.
        getBase64(info.file.originFileObj, imageUrl => {
          this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
          this.loading = false;
        });
      }
    },
    beforeUpload(file) {
      const isJpgOrPng = file.type === 'image/jpeg' || file.type === 'image/png';
      if (!isJpgOrPng) {
        this.$message.error('You can only upload JPG file!');
      }
      const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
      if (!isLt2M) {
        this.$message.error('Image must smaller than 2MB!');
      }
      return isJpgOrPng && isLt2M;
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style>
.avatar-uploader > .ant-upload {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
.ant-upload-select-picture-card i {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #999;
}

.ant-upload-select-picture-card .ant-upload-text {
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #666;
}
</style>
```

it'll return

```
error POST https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET will produced after upload file. only file around 10-50 mb is allowed.
```

i've try by leave action as empty but it'll use base domain with path null as post api.
is there any other way to to leave action as empty so that it can run straight to @change instead stuck in action other than create own api?

Comment: Any update on this? I'm running into the same issue now with react

Comment: Are any changes here? Have the same problem(

Comment: did you find any solution i'm facing same issue?